# AndroidPlot missing start point of graph

Tags: android, androidplot

I'm using Bar chart from example on website.

I realize the chart is missing starting point (0), and the bar is over drawing range.

[image: screenshot]

Did anyone have some problem with me?

- Android version 4.4.2
- compileSdkVersion 23
- buildToolsVersion "23.0.3

[Source codes](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/androidplot/CVVSlBWH3kw)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include *the desired behavior*, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like all the points are actually there, but there are a couple issues in the sample that make it appear broken:

1 - the domain and origin label paint appear to be set to white, so it's blending with the background color. this can be corrected in your plot's xml by adding:

```
ap:rangeOriginTickLabelTextColor="#000"
ap:domainOriginTickLabelTextColor="#000"
```

2 - This happens with wide bars and multiple bars side by side.  There will be a separate param to control grid insets in the next release, but for now, the most straightforward solution is to set a fixed domain boundary that includes some extra space:

```
plot.setDomainBoundaries(minVal - someSpace, maxVal + someSpace, BoundaryMode.FIXED);
```